# Textfieldparser Delimiters

Tags: vb.net, file-io, text-files, delimiter

I'm currently busy coding a hangman game in VB.NET.
As a wordlist, I have a textfile containing 1520 words, each one seperated by a new line...

The best I could think of to get a random word is with a Randomize() function.
Then getting the word from the line # which was randomly generated.

Only to find out just now, that this method:

```
Using parser As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser_
("filepath")
        parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
```

doesn't allow me to use a new line as a delimiter...

Considering all words have different lengths/widths, I can't use this either:

```
parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
```

Is there any better way for me to extract the word from that random line?

If not, what would be the delimiter I should use for this and how do I quickly change the breaklines into that new delimiter without resorting to Office?

Also, how can I use the textfieldparser to get the file from resources? 
When I tried using 
*my.resources.filename*
instead of *"filepath"*, it gave me an ArgumentException due to "invalid characters in the path".

Comment: TextFieldParser is meant to parse CSV-like files. It follows the rfc4180 guideline. (though you can change the delimiter, it still relies upon the crlf line delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to load your text file into a string collection, then grab the random index of the collection

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim Reader As New StreamReader("C:\WordList.txt")
Dim line As String

Do
    line = Reader.ReadLine()
    list.Add(line)
Loop Until line Is Nothing

Reader.Close()
```

Comment: I suppose with that code, I can just use the randomized number as an index for the "list()" variable?

Comment: yes, and make sure the index for the list() should start from 1 not 0

Comment: Do you mean the randomized index or the actual index lists? Because I can just change the randomize code to go between 0 & 1519 :P

Comment: whatever you get from the randomize code then plus 1 to make it between 1 to 1520

Comment: I think you might be mistaken :) Just had it print the word into the immeadiate screen while using word = list(1520), which didn't work :P
Meaning the randomized index should be between 0 & 1519 and not 1 & 1520 :)

Or I'm just too tired to fully understand what you mean :P Give me a break, it's nearly 5 am here :(

Comment: Oh by the way @Nick, any chance you know how I can get the streamreader to work with a resource file instead of a hard path?

Comment: As I remember the index range of the collections should start with 1. But you can try from 0 to 1519, may be I am wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "get the streamreader to work with a resource file instead of a hard path?" The filename is just a string, you can make is as a variable if you like

Comment: I mean use this:

`Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(my.resources.wordlist)`
Instead of this:

`Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\wordlist.txt")`

Comment: The file name is just a string, sure you can get it from your resource

Comment: The index range on collections in VB.NET is 0 to Count-1. If you were using VBA or VB6 the default would start at 1.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation @nvuono

Comment: I must have had the VB version wrong then, my bad :)
Anyway, @Nick, how should I enter the resource then? Since for some reason when I use "my.resources.wordlist", I get an ArgumentException "invalid characters in path"

Comment: @Yorrick, check your path from the resource at run-time, or if you can post here so we can have a look

Comment: @Nick, well the file is stored within the project's resources and frankly I have no idea on how to get the path to it, I never needed it before.

Comment: When you say the file is stored within the project's resources, I am thinking that may not be a file, it is the actual word list, that means you don't need to use StreamReader but access the word list directly. e.g. Treat `my.resources.wordlist` as a variable just like string.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the words into a string array with [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx). One line of code:

```
Dim words() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

To select a random word, use [Rnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
Randomize()
Dim randomWord As String = words(CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd * words.Length)))
```